# Check if an input is an array or not, and print the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The code is not returning the expected result: I want to return "true" if it is an array on the "checkArray" div and "false" if it is not, depending on the user input.

```
<input type="text" id="data" placeholder="Insert data">
<button type="submit" onclick="checkArray()">Check</button>
<div id="checkArray"></div>
<script>
function is_array(data) {
    if (data instanceof Array) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
function checkArray() {
    var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
    document.getElementById("checkArray").innerHTML = is_array(data);
}
```

Comment: [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) should be supported by most browsers.  Though, the value of a text field will _always_ be a string, it will never be an array.

Comment: I tried with Array.isArray() but it is not working

Comment: Because it's a text field, and it will always give you a string.  What data are you expecting to have in the text field?  Are you having users enter something like `[1,2,3]` into the field?  In that case, you'd have to try to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the data and see if it's an array.

Comment: Ok, I will try that... Thank you!

Comment: If the user put "apple" the result should be false and if it is "[apple]" the result should be true

Comment: `JSON.parse()` would work if the input was `["apple"]`.  If it's just `[apple]`, then you'll need to "parse" the input on your own (possibly by checking if the input starts with `[`, ends with `]`, and then `.split()` on `,`).

Comment: I tried with JSON.parse() but it is not working yet... For the input yes, I think the correct way for a string it is ["apple"], I forgot that before, but I put for example [1,2,3,4] and that I think must work with JSON.parse only, but don't

Comment: I realized that it is working, but I have to put quotes in the input field. "some text" return false, and [1,2,3] return true... How can I do in order to not write the quotes for text?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for opening and closing array brackets at the start and end of your input value, you could replace your `is_array(data)` function with the below code. Although the type of your input value will be string anyway.

```
function is_array(data) {
    return data[0] + data[data.length - 1] === "[]"
}
```

Comment: This is useful! But this accepts an array like this [asdfg] and this is not an array, must be ["asdfg"]